# Accidentally sent offline email

Tags: gmail

So on my HTC device whilst offline I jokingly typed an email which if sent will screw me up and then I sent it after by accident. Since then I haven't connected my device to any internet at all as I am to scared to. I sent it using the gmail app on my phone so has the email already been sent or perhaps is it only on my phone(I have unlinked the account from my phone to be safe). If the email ha sent been sent could anyone be kind enough to tell me how to delete the e,ail before it is sent or is it already too late

Comment: I am afraid damage is done. Next time use [inbox trick](https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/make-use-of-gmails-undo-send-on-android/)

Comment: Has the email already been sent or will it send as soon as I connect to internet on my phone even though I unlinked the gmail account

Comment: *I sent it after by accident*- were you connected to Internet? If not, it if note sent but would be sent when you connect. My earlier comment was assuming that you were connected. That's my understanding. Others can share their experiences

Comment: I was still not connected and have unlinked my account from my phone so is it ok for me to actually turn on Internet on my phone and if yes should I be fine as long as I don't log unto gmail account on my phone but should be ok if I log on with a different device

Comment: Since this is a serious issue for you, I suggest you wait for others to answer with practical experience but logically , to me, it should be fine to be connected as long as account is not linked

Answer (score 0):

Check sent items from any other device and UNINSTALL GMAIL ASAP. This may help.
If it is in the sent items then, I'm sorry, it must have arrived.
Also if you removed Google account from settings, then you should have signed it of Gmail instead.
Uninstalling may help.